# A more reliable way to get rid of chopstick splinters other than rubbing them?

Tags: food, food-safety, wood

Whenever I try to rub my chopsticks together (regardless of etiquette; the places I go to aren't that fancy) to get rid those splinters on the cheap wooden chopsticks, I usually end up with more splinters than before all over my chopsticks.

Is there a better way to get rid of the splinters, by a different way of rubbing them, or otherwise? Thanks!

Comment: Do you notice any splinters before rubbing the chopsticks together?

Comment: Some people travel with chopsticks, the kind that are lacquered, to avoid the use those 'break apart' one time ones.

Comment: @Lawrence, Yes, there's quite a bit when I first split them apart

Answer (score 1):

keep a small piece of wire wool handy, rub each chopstick gently and then wipe with a napkin

Comment: Huh, steel wool! I'm guessing the very fine kind, since it's wood that can easily splinter? Creative, but ideally it would be either just by rubbing the sticks or with something I'm already carrying. Thanks though!

Comment: any - with steel wool its more about the degree of "give" that the material being rubbed down has. Even coarse wool would do since the wood is softer than the wool. Keep some in your pocket in a plastic bag

Comment: are there other uses for steel wool, where having it can be really handy? Also, won't the steel wool scratch away at the plastic bag, eventually causing holes?

Comment: @StevenChoi no, it won't - it only abrades **with pressure**. You know when you buy headphones they come in a little resealable bag? re-use one of those.